# How to call a method after a yield instruction in the same frame?

Tags: c#, unity

When I run this script...

```
int frameCount;

void Start()
{
    frameCount = 0;
    StartCoroutine(first());
}

void Update()
{
    frameCount++;
    Debug.Log("Frame " + frameCount);
}

public IEnumerator first()
{
    Method1();
    yield return StartCoroutine(second());
    Method2();
}

public IEnumerator second()
{
    Method3();
    yield return null;
}

void Method1() { Debug.Log("Method1"); }
void Method2() { Debug.Log("Method2"); }
void Method3() { Debug.Log("Method3"); }
```

I get the following output:

```
Method1
Method3
Frame 1
Frame 2
Method2
```

How can I call all three methods in same frame without changing the code structure? The output i want:

```
Method1
Method3
Method2
Frame1
Frame2
```

---

**Note:** If this is not possible, please show me whether i can get this output (without changing the code structure):

```
Method1
Method3
Frame1
Method2
Frame2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue seems to be the over-use of yields.  You don't need to yield on `second()` the way it's being used here so your `first()` function should look like this:

```
public IEnumerator first()
{
    Method1();
    StartCoroutine(second());
    Method2();
    yield break;
}
```

### Important note:

The code in `second()` will only complete execution before `Method2()` is called if it doesn't `yield` on anything extra.  Your `yield return StartCoroutine(second())` will wait for all of `second()` to finish before `Method2()` but the way I have it written (without the `yield return`) will only perform operations *before the first `yield` in `second()`*.  Since the first `yield` is *after* `Method3()` I assume this is fine but since this is a simplification of your actual code, I want to make that clear.

As another note, if you're adding a `yield` just to get an `IEnumerator` to compile, `yield break;` is sufficient.

---

I've run this myself and get:

```
Method1
Method3
Method2
Frame 1
Frame 2
```

Comment: Then i guess they will start to work in a mixed order if i have a yield instruction in `second()` right?

Comment: @SamedTarıkÇETİN Yes.  If `second()` had a `yield` before `Method3()` then `first()` will get to `Method2()` before `second()` got to `Method3()`.

Comment: Than it seems like i have to modify my code structure to achieve what i want in the background of this question. Thank you.

Comment: @SamedTarıkÇETİN No problem!

Answer (score 1):

Change your Start method from `void` to `IEnumerator` and use one of the examples below.

> Method1
>   Method3
>   Method2
>   Frame1
>   Frame2

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    Method1();
    Method3();
    Method2();
    yield return null; // frame
    yield return null; // frame
}
```

> Method1
>   Method3
>   Frame1
>   Method2
>   Frame2

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    Method1();
    Method3();
    yield return null; // frame
    Method2();
    yield return null; // frame
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir, but you changed the code structure; i need Method3 to be called on a seperate IEnumerator.

Comment: You are not allowed to change the structure of any of the methods?

Comment: My actual script is way more complicated and heavy, i simplified it into basics to ask the question. I seperated a single IEnumerator into single-responsible IEnumerators to improve readibility for further improvments. That is why i'm asking Method3 to be called on a seperate IEnumerator.

Comment: "yield return null;" in the method "second" waits a frame. Needed?

Comment: That is not a thing i want but when i leave an IEnumerator without any yield instructions it gives me an error that says it should return something.

Comment: use yield break instead

Comment: I tried, it gives the same output.